# Loop to Insert Row, Copy data

Tags: excel, vba

I give up. I just spent four hours trying to figure out why this macro will not work.
I want it to take the given source Range, cycle through it using the `For` Loop and copy the Value to a different column.

I want it to start at the given destination cell and

- enter the value
- create a new row using Insert (entire row, not just insert into that column. I want to fit the data within an existing set of rows)
- Not override the Marker that designates the end point of the destination column. There is data below it which needs to be kept.

I can't figure out why

- In one instance of procedure, it enters the value but then wipes out the data as it inserts the next row.
- In the second instance, it skips a row and obliterates the end of column marker

Note that I'm not looking for clever, elegant solutions to the problem, in an effort to teach myself the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) paradigm, I want to keep things really basic. As I get better at understanding the basics, I'll try some advanced tricks.

TIA

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim firstRow As Range, lastRow As Range
Dim source As Range, destination As Range
Dim readCell As Range

Set firstRow = Range("F2")
Set lastRow = Range("F20")
Set destination = Range("A21")


Set source = Range(firstRow.Address(False, False) & ":" & lastRow.Address(False, False))

For Each readCell In source
    destination.Select
    destination.Value = readCell.Value

    If (readCell.Address(False, False) = lastRow.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        Exit For
    Else
       'destination.Select
    End If

    'MsgBox (destination.Value)
    destination.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
    Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some hints:

Given that `firstRow` and `lastRow` are single cells, no need for the `Address` stuff.  Use

```
Set source = Range(firstRow,  lastRow)
```

In `destination.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp`, because you are applying `Insert` to an entire row, `Shift` makes no difference.  Use

```
destination.EntireRow.Insert
```

The inserted row in placed above `destination`, and `destination` is shifted down.    So the first iteration of the for loop does this

1. Set `destination` to `A21`
2. Insert row, shifting `destination` to `A22`
3. Set `desination` down one row, ie `A23`

The next iteration will then overwrite the data originally in `A22`, now in `A23`

I think you want

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim firstRow As Range, lastRow As Range
    Dim destination As Range
    Dim readCell As Range

    Set firstRow = Range("F2")
    Set lastRow = Range("F20")
    Set destination = Range("A21")

    For Each readCell In Range(firstRow, lastRow)
        destination.Value = readCell.Value
        destination.EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Insert
        Set destination = destination.Offset(1, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.
I don't understand why that was so difficult to recognize.
My programming mistakes are always something ridiculously simple.

Answer (score 1):

Very commendable that you want to understand as well as solve

It is easier to use a row counter than increments from a fixed destination. This minor adjustment

- avoids `Select`
- uses a counter, `lngRow`, to control the new row and new values

  **`code`**

  ```
  Sub Macro1()
  Dim readCell As Range
  Dim lngRow As Long
  For Each readCell In Range("F2:F20")
      [a21].Offset(lngRow, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
      [a21].Offset(lngRow, 0).Value = readCell.Value
      lngRow = lngRow + 1
  Next
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Huh!
That's interesting.
Is there some overhead in using select?
Thanks

Comment: @KenIngram Yes. It adds time, and in some cases can cause errors, or trigger further macro events. I have further tidied my code to keep your loop intact but to remove the unnecessary range positions